# Transposing a row data in multiple rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have data in the database in the below format

[image]

And I want output data in this format

```
BudgetCategoryId | CostCenterDepartmentId | CostCenter | AccountNo | Amount    | Timestamp
714              | 135                    |  12010194  |       110 | 102000.00 | 01-01-2020
```

[image]

Basically **timestamp** in the desired result is `'01-' + <'MONTH'> + <'YEAR'>`

I tried transposing, pivot, unpivot but unfortunately unable to get the desired result.

Column Names:

```
Id | BudgetCategoryId | CostCenterDepartmentId | Year | AccountNo | CostCenter | Month1 | Month2 | Month3 | Month4 | Month5 | Month6 | Month7 | Month8 | Month9 | Month10 | Month11 | Month12 | Budget
```

PS: I am very new in SQL (RDBMS)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do it in several steps: first unpivot, then calculate the timestamp.

Unpivoting would be

```
SELECT BudgetCategoryId, CostCenterDepartmentId, CostCenter, AccountNo, Year, Amount, Month
  FROM (
    SELECT BudgetCategoryId, CostCenterDepartmentId, CostCenter, AccountNo, Year,
      Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12
      FROM table) p
  UNPIVOT (
    Amount FOR Month IN (Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12)
)
```

The timestamp can be calculated as `DATEFROMPARTS(Year, CAST(SUBSTRING(Month, 6, LEN(Month) - 5)), 1)` and it might work to add it as an extra field in the above `SELECT`, or you might need to do an extra `SELECT` on the above result.